# How can I set `grant type` when using `google_identity_platform_oauth_idp_config` in terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am using `google_identity_platform_oauth_idp_config` in terraform to deploy identity to GCP. I have read this doc: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/identity_platform_oauth_idp_config but I can't find where I can set the grant type.

By default it set it to `Implicit flow`. How can I set it to `Code flow`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/identity_platform_oauth_idp_config#argument-reference), if you set the `client_secret` argument it should enable the OIDC code flow.